# Convert function params to Hash object in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, types, parameters, applicationcontroller

I have to make a change to an API developed in Ruby On Rails that looks like this:

```
class V0::PythonsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authorize_request

  # POST v0/python/import
  def import
    result = { status: :error }
    data = eval(AwsTool.decrypt(params["code"])).first
    if data.class == Hash
      user = User.find_by(id: data[:ot_user_id])
      activity_type = ActivityType.find_by(id: data[:activity_type])
      if user.nil?
        result[:msg] = "user not found"
      elsif activity_type.nil?
        result[:msg] = "activity type not found"
      else...
```

I pass to it some data in the "code" param, that is then decrypted and then explored. I want to add an if clause so when I call the API from a different origin no encryption and decryption takes place. So I have made this change:

```
class V0::PythonsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authorize_request

  # POST v0/python/import
  def import
    result = { status: :error }
  if params["origin"] != 'trusted'
    data = eval(AwsTool.decrypt(params["code"])).first
  else
    data = params["code"]
  end
  if data.class == Hash
    user = User.find_by(id: data[:ot_user_id])
    activity_type = ActivityType.find_by(id: data[:activity_type])
    ...
```

The problem is that data.class is not a Hash object, its a String. I have tried different solutions to convert the object from String to Hash like t_hash and other similar functions but they didn't work. I got some errors about params not being permitted, I tried to add the permit to them but still fails.

Any other idea?

Comment: What does data.class look like?

Comment: I'm getting String if I try `p data.class`

Comment: What is your `params["code"]` looks like?

Comment: What if you try just `p data`?

Comment: Hi guys, if I put `p data` the result is like this: `{:ot_user_id=>"3", :query_date_time=>"2019-02-27T22:00:21:848587", :theactivities=>[{:activity_value=>"5500", :activity_date_time=>"2019-02-27"}]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is failing because you forgot to call `eval` on the code. Do this:

```
data = eval(params["code"])
```

By the way, evaling input is very dangerous.  I hope you trust whoever is using this API.

Comment: Thanks @infused, I have just tried this and worked well. The 'eval()' could be used to inject malicious code? or is there another danger to take into account? Could be another solution without using eval?

Comment: don't use eval. this is super insecure. not sure what you are doing, but try to evaluate code differently. Or call predefined methods with params from URL